# Track multiple admin git usage on production

Tags: git

I would like to know what would be the best practice when multiple admin needs to update production server from git, major action would be a git pull, but ideally we would like to track who did what using git on production server.

Is there any option by which we can use SSH key of admin for git on production, but every time for a git pull for eg, asks the ssh pass phrase, so that action gets tied up with the admin who is working on it at that time?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to install an [authorization layer](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/how.html#%283%29) in front of git on the server: that is what **[gitolite](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-on-the-Server-Gitolite)** does.

And gitolite comes with logs: `~git/.gitolite/logs` which records the IP of any request (pull/push/clone): that way, you can reconcile who did what when.